# cannot create httpClient in java

Tags: java

I want to create HTTPclient. using httpClient-4.3.3.jar and httpcore-4.3.2.
libraries. but `HttpClientBuilder.create().build()` does not return anything, even the exception. what`s wrong? can you help me?

```
public final String URL;

public HTTPClient(String URL)
{
    this.URL = URL;
}

public String getData()
{
    String response = new String();
    try
    {
        trace("start creating client");
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        trace("client : " + client.toString());
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(this.URL);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if(responseEntity != null)
        {
            response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        }
        if(response.isEmpty())
        {
            trace("response is null");
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return response;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException | ParseException ex)
    {
        trace(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: can you please add the relevant part of the exception to your question?

Comment: Do you get a NullPointerException on line `trace("client : " + client.toString());` or `HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);`? Otherwhise your statement that `HttpClientBuilder.create().build()` does not return anything (meaning client is `null`) is not correct.

Comment: Could you please explain why you think that it returns nothing? Does it throw en exception or not?

Comment: trace("client : " + client.toString()); << it is not completing.  it doesn`t throws anything. 
trace("start creating client"); << this works, and than the program stops and waits for response.